# How to read the files from one directory and give the file as input of another stored procedure using shell scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i am new to writing shell scripts and i have a directory called XML_Files which contains the list of xml files

```
01.xml

02.xml

03.xml

04.xml
```

i wanted to read all xml files one by one and send the files to my stored procedure as input argument. so that the stored procedure will process the each xml file one by one accordingly.

I tried to use the for loop to achieve this , but i couldn't get the expected results. it only took the file directory path. Can someone help what i missed in the below script:

```
XML_FILES='ls -l $Xml_Files/*.xml'
for f in XML_FILES
do
<<Stored procedure>> $f
if [ $? = 0 ] 
then 
  mv $f $XML_Proccesed_Dir/
else
    mv $f $XML_error_Dir/
fi
done
```

i am looking for something which can pick the file from the /xml_files directory and send the files to the stored procedure as an input argument to process the xml files.

Comment: Do you have any sub-directories under `XML_Files` directory?

Comment: NO i dont have any sub directories

Comment: Then you can write a short script in which you first go to the desired directory ,like:`cd /desired/directory/` and apply the `for` loop,like:`for i in *.xml; do <<Stored procedure>> $i; done`

Comment: thanks..i used ${Xml_Files}/*.xml to pick my files and its working

Comment: *"... but i couldn't get the expected results"* is not a good problem statement. What is the problem or error? Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww Thanks for your mention..the link which you provided was helpful and I will correct it in future...

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the wildcard expansion in bash to get the list of xml files inside folder.

```
for f in ${Xml_Files}/*.xml; do 
    something ${f}
    ....
done
```

`${f}` in this loop will be in form:

```
${Xml_Files}/01.xml
${Xml_Files}/02.xml
${Xml_Files}/03.xml
${Xml_Files}/04.xml
```

If you need ${f} to be in some other format you should clarify the question more.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `find` to execute a given command on every files found. Example:

```
find ${Xml_Files} -name '*.xml' -type f -exec something {} \;
```

This will search every file (`-type f`) with extension xml (`-name '*.xml'`) in the directory `${Xml_Files}` and execute `something x` on every `x` found.

You can also use `find` to execute short bash script, e.g.:

```
find ${Xml_Files} -name '*.xml' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo {}' \;
```